# VSCode run button will not output my .py scripts

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm just configuring my VSCode to run python and I started off with hello world, the run button in the top left returns:

```
C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe "c:/Users/ogdar/VSCODE FOLDERS/Lesson01/hello.py"
-bash: C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe: No such file or directory
```

but python.exe is in that path.

I tried changing the python default interpreter to a different path but it produced the same results with the new path. Running the absolute file path works of course but if there is a way to have the run button work I'd love that.

Comment: I am using the recommended command interpreter by VSCode

Comment: is "_but python.exe is in that path_" part of the error message?

Comment: @Dgatsby Please [edit] the question to add details so that the info is all together. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: How did you install Bash? I don't use Windows anymore, but last I remember, `C:` paths weren't directly accessible [from WSL](https://superuser.com/questions/1066261/how-to-access-windows-folders-from-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows) or [MinGW](/q/11376899/how-do-i-navigate-my-windows-folders-like-c-drive-in-msys) or [Cygwin](/q/1850920/how-to-navigate-to-a-directory-in-c-with-cygwin).

Comment: Can you elaborate on what **Run Button** you are using?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT the run python file button on the top on right corner

Comment: Check your workspace. Read [document about getting start](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) may help